# How to get rid of the term with $xy$?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm trying to put this conic on an identifiable form.

$$4x^2-4xy+y^2+20x+40y=0$$

I know that the term $xy$ implies that I need to rotate the conic so that $xy$ vanishes. But I've read on some books but I couldn't figure out how to do it. It seems that there is a system that needs to be solved, and this system involves some trigonometric funcions.

I thought about the following: As the term with $xy$ is going to be eliminated, I guess I should write:

$$4x^2-4xy+y^2+20x+40y=0\\ 4\left(x+\cfrac{5}{2}\right)^2+(y+20)^2-4xy-90=0$$

Perhaps the center of this conic is $(-5/2,-20)$. I guess that knowing the center must be important to something.

Comment: The matrix for the quadratic form $4x^2-4xy+y^2$ is $A =  \left(\begin{matrix}4 & -2\\ -2 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$ right? So to bring it to a form free of $xy$ term you need to diagonalize $A$ (in general).

Comment: @r9m There are two matrixes. This one you mentioned and:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
{x}&{y}&{1}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
{a}&{b/2}&{d/2}\\ 
{b/2}&{c}&{e/2}\\ 
{d/2}&{e/2}&{f}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
{x}\\ 
{y}\\ 
{z}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @r9m What's the difference of them? I know that this matrix form is associated (can be expanded) to a quadratic form. But I'm not sure what your matrix does.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** The first three terms can together be rewritten as $$(2 x - y)^2,$$ suggesting part of a change of variable that will eliminate the cross-term.

Comment: I need to do a change of variable such that $xy=0$, right?

Comment: You need to make some change of variable from $(x, y)$ to $(u, v)$ so that, once written in $u, v$ the l.h.s. contains no $uv$ term.

Comment: One silly doubt: In the book I'm reading, it says about eliminating the linear terms, in another place I've read, it seems that the objective is to eliminate the term with $xy$. Are they equivalent? There is also another book I have that says that the objective seems to be to write the conic in the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. I'm a little confused.

Comment: No, the $xy$ term is a particular quadratic monomial, eliminating the linear terms is a separate normalization; once the cross-term has been eliminated, it's enough to apply an appropriate change of coordinates $(x, y) \mapsto (x - a, y - b)$ to eliminate the linear terms (in general this introduces a constant term).

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x=x'-\frac{g+hy}a$ will not only remove xy term, but will also make the process easier.All the best.